# How to label a line in a tikz diagram with an arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, labels

I think the question is pretty self explanatory. It boggles my mind that I couldn't find an existing answer to this question.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \angle in {0,120,...,240} {
        \begin{scope}[rotate=\angle]
        \draw[dotted] (0,0) -- node[above] {Want an arrow here} ++(0:2) -- ++(120:2);
        \draw[dotted] (0,0) -- ++(60:2) -- ++(180:2);
        \filldraw (0:0) circle(2pt);
        \filldraw[color=red] (0:0) ++(0:2) circle(2pt);
        \filldraw[color=blue] (0:0) ++(0:2) ++(120:2) circle(2pt);
        \end{scope}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Not so self explanatory, I fear. Where do you want the arrow? Instead of the text "want an arrow here"? On the line under it? On the path under it? (BTW: Welcome! and please next time post a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))

Comment: Is `node[above, rotate=\angle] {$\to$}` what you need? (notice that your scope `rotate` will not apply to contents of nodes if you do not use `transform shape`).

Comment: @Rmano, I should've added a hand drawn picture of what I wanted, but you managed to provide a great solution anyway. I will remember to do that next time I ask a question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three different options, depending on what you really want/need:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
     \foreach \angle in {0,120,...,240} {
        \begin{scope}[rotate=\angle]
        \draw (0:0) edge[cyan, -Stealth] (0:2);
        \draw[yshift=0.2cm] (0:.75) edge[green, -Stealth] ++(0:.5);
        \draw[dotted] (0,0) -- node[above, rotate=\angle] {$\to$} ++(0:2) -- ++(120:2);
        \draw[dotted] (0,0) -- ++(60:2) -- ++(180:2);
        \filldraw (0:0) circle(2pt);
        \filldraw[color=red] (0:0) ++(0:2) circle(2pt);
        \filldraw[color=blue] (0:0) ++(0:2) ++(120:2) circle(2pt);
        \end{scope}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think I was looking for the green one.

Comment: @Rmano i could not understand what is the `$\to$` reference -- kindly educate

Comment: @jsbibra it's just a math formula with the `$\to$` symbol alone.